# Require new users to post all of the needed parts of a question separately

Tags: discussion, questions, question-quality

Background: Today, I decided to try and re-join SO to answer questions... And immediately, on the very first question I found, I was forced to revert to my old pattern: posting a frequently required [comment of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586177/issues-with-a-perl-program#comment36201736_23586177):

> "issues with a program" isn't really enough information to help you. The correct way to describe the issues is: **(1) Input data; (2) Your actual output; (3) The output you EXPECT that differs from #2; (4) Any error messages you get** (<sub>I was pleasantly surprised that the user posted their code :)</sub>)

---

Therefore, my proposal is to follow a good UX design paradigm - **when you need people to provide N separate chunks of information, use a separate form field for each chunk**.

More specifically, **for new users only** - say those with less than 50 rep OR with less than 3 questions with +2 votes each - **require their questions to SO to be posted via a form that has 6 different fields** instead of one textarea:

1. Problem you are trying to solve
2. Code you tried to solve it
3. Specific issue you have with running your code

   (A good design would be multiple choice option "compile error"/"runtime error"/"no output"/"incorrect output" + text area)
4. Specific input you give to your code
5. Specific expected behavior/output you expect from your code
6. Exact output/behavior you get from your code, and how it differs from #5

---

***Benefits***

This would solve 2 distinct use cases, each of which results in poor quality SO questions:

1. User who doesn't know yet how to ask a good question. The form would provide that guidance to them.

   This would have two benefits

   - we would get more good and less bad questions, by requiring posters to learn what parts are needed for a good question as an integral part of asking it
   - **and** we would have less bad feelings on all sides from "well, I get treated badly for simply not knowing the intricacies of asking good questions" from well intentioned but poorly informed newbies, who are denigrated via "your question is crap" from well intentioned but tired of volumes of crap old timers.
2. Help vampires, who simply don't care.

   Those would either (hopefully) be fully repelled by the added barrier of needing to fill out more than a zero-effort freeform text box; OR would drastically simplify the task of detecting and DVing/VTCing their questions as evidenced by crap in most of the required fields.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to use a good UX design paradigm to suit a well-defined problem.

Comment: Believe it or not, this has actually been proposed before. Searching...

Comment: @Cupcake - I'm *shocked*... Well, not. But probably not on MSO, as the proposal is very SO specific.

Comment: @DVK no no, on MSO...still searching...

Comment: This sounds like it would step users through the process of posting a "please debug my code for me" question.

Comment: @DVK found them. See [Thwart publishing duplicate and low quality questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253317/456814), and if you're interested, maybe [How to figure out if a SO question is viable prior to posting?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252327/456814) too.

Comment: My worry is that whilst poor questions don't fit your template because of omission, the best questions don't fit either. Virtually none of my favourite questions fit the bug-report style post you're advocating. Once you've got a template for beginners people will start to think of it as automatically bad to not fit the template. Summary: template enforces mediocrity and will foster mediocrity.

Comment: @DVK I actually just wrote up this exact recommendation and was in the process of posting it when MSO suggested this thread (not sure why I didn't find it before during my research). This would I think make a big difference in quality of questions by leading (mostly) new users through the steps of framing good SO-compliant questions.  Surprised this hasn't been upvoted more.

Comment: This is a great suggestion! And the `code` field could not only force code formatting - but *make the user do it*, so that they learn! i.e. "Hey, you need four spaces on each line to format code properly; make sure the rest of your indentation makes sense, too."

Comment: @AndrewC Is that not just an issue of finding the sweet-spot in laxity of the template though? Stricter than the current: "put everything here", but not so strict as: "enter things here you probably don't need". The order (e.g. of code and text) could be adjusted to cause variation, and to better fit the structure (and encourage one) of the poster's post.

Comment: @OllieFord I think you missed my point entirely. The best questions aren't _related_ to "I have a bug in my code I don't get." (I admit the _worst_ questions are basically "I got some error message. How should I fix it?" with little other info, but this template doesn't even ask them to paste the complete error message.) The __main problem__ with this template is that it doesn't allow for clever, well-thought-through, deep questions. It will turn SO into programmer-bugs-only-please, which would spoil it horribly in my view. Only three questions out of my 30 favourited ones have errors at all.

Comment: @AndrewC No, I don't think I did. I'm just saying that you're highlighting that such a template needs more thought, and to be less restrictive in style than is offered here. Note also this is suggested for *new users* who are much less likely to be asking questions similar to your favourites.

Comment: @OllieFord I'm not saying that the template requires careful thought, I'm saying we need to _not have_ the template. The rules you apply to new users beccome the new orthodoxy for the whole site. Please bear in mind that some new users are very experienced programmers. You don't get good at asking good questions by following a ticklist, just as you don't get good at answering by following a ticklist - you learn. A template is the wrong tool for teaching this, because it teaches a lie - that your question quality is determined by its adherence to a specific format.

Comment: I can promise you that you would still get a vast quantity of poorly-thought through questions from people who have not read the instructions, but questions that don't fit the new SO format will start to get downvoted or commented against by users who grew up with the new rules. After a while they will start to get closed. You'll teach intelligent users with deep questions that they ought not to ask them here; it will all become mundane. We get burned out to varying degrees by poor questions, yes, but if you teach against the interesting questions, there would be no point in visiting at all.

Comment: I posted a question when I had very low reputation - asking it was my original motivation for joining SO. It would have been much longer without being any better if I had had to fit it in the proposed format. As written, it got 8 upvotes, 0 downvotes, and the only edits were me adding results of attempting suggested solutions, and changes related to adding and awarding a bounty, so presumably it was considered OK by the community.

Comment: I think 1. and 2. would fit all kinds of questions (and was going to propose it before finding this post). I'd add the links suggested by the question form, with the reason why they don't answer the question.

Comment: related: [Providing a template of a good question for a user's first go](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253152/providing-a-template-of-a-good-question-for-a-users-first-go)

Answer (score 10):

The main problem is that this prevents posting a good question in the current format, where all information is provided, in the order that makes the most sense to a coherent presentation.

I know that I prefer the formatting of a well-written StackOverflow question to the bug reports which are submitted using a bunch of disparate fields as you suggest.

Furthermore, StackOverflow questions are not all created alike.  Conceptual questions and debugging questions do not have strictly the same parts.

Comment: The fact that it's only enforced for low-rep users isn't much of a problem. We could also allow editing the question right away after it was posted, that should take care of the presentation by allowing the author to change it if the formatting is bad if he cares, but most crap question authors won't care anyway.

Comment: @AndréDaniel - THAT. And also, if you really know what you're doing, you can post the "correct" question in on of the 5 textareas; and N/A in the others

Comment: @DVK allowing n/a or empty fields would defeat the purpose of the feature though, the users would just dump their crap question in the first field and leave everything else empty.

Answer (score 2):

This is something we've been thinking about. When we revamped both the static and Machine Learning-based analysis of questions as they're posted, we realized that there were variables that we couldn't account for:

- "How do I" questions differ quite a bit from "Why am I" questions, in terms of the information necessary to answer them. This makes it hard to know what's "good", even from the language cues we can take.
- It's very hard to train machine learning on known "good" or "bad", because ML really can't account for things where the words of someone who didn't do a simple search before asking look great.

In other words, it's terribly difficult to catch what they *might* have forgotten, or could have done better and prompt them on how and why they should fix it before posting. If we were going to gain any more ground here, it was pretty obvious that we needed to come up with a more guided way for new users to ask questions.

Let's completely set aside the fact that such a feature would be heavily designed around the needs of Stack Overflow, and probably not that useful to other sites. While we would try our best to make as much of it reusable as possible (e.g. if Ask Ubuntu needed it) - we'd need to build it very specifically for Stack Overflow and be willing to accept that it might only be useful there.

That gets us off to a good start, we then have to consider the following goals:

1. It ***must*** appear to be easier and 'better' than just typing freeform in the question box to a new user in a major hurry.

Why should I go through an undetermined amount of steps if I can simply complete a single step that wants me to press a single button? This is due in 30 minutes!

2. We ***can't*** force it on new users. While we'd run tests to see what happens if it's the default interface for people that have never asked a question, or perhaps only a couple questions that are zero or negatively scored, we have to preserve the option to just use the classic editor.

Well, *initially* we can't. We have to A/B test the crap out of it so we're making decisions on data rather than intuition, and we have to make sure we didn't introduce accessibility hurdles that simply can't be solved satisfactorily in a wizard that still does what we need it to do. And even more reasons. Suffice to say, we've got to build it with a way out of it.

3. Going back to #1, we can't have too many prompts. The more we put in the weaker the results we'll see. This is where we start to get *really* Stack Overflow specific, and where the incentive for new users to actually use this thing is critical to establish.

The first question is really important, because it's a question of endeavor. Are you debugging or writing? Because the rest of our prompts kind of depend on this context to be relevant. Now consider that the sum of the most poorly written questions came from people that *probably* didn't know the answer to that question. This is where containing this in a lightweight interface gets .. interesting. This is solve-able, and half of you are probably screaming the names of two button labels at your monitor right now - but it's only the start of it. They also need help understanding which one to click.

After that, there can be .. four, at most *five* .. more steps, and title / tagging are pretty important places to help them.

So let's get to the point I had before I went off on a tangent. I'm willing to put work into this, but I'd really like it if (together) we can vett the idea as being tenable before we get too far out in the weeds with it.

And here's the first question - what does success look like here? We're not going to get perfect questions from this, but we *might* be able to aim for a higher percentage of stuff being more easily salvageable. Well, that's my opinion, anyway. But we're looking at a lot of work, could this really be as big of a win as intuition suggests?

The best approach might be taking several stabs at it on jsfiddle that actually produces questions that can be copied / pasted to the site. Anyway, that's where my train of thought ended on it as we considered it heavily last year.

Comment: Does my suggestion: [Could some bad questions be avoided with additional prompting?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting?noredirect=1#comment308579_260039) not address some of your concerns? It would be  a single prompt that would collate the potential shortcomings of a post that can be read and effectively dismissed with a checkbox. It would give the user some feedback but not be do preventative when coming to actually posting.

Comment: Wait, is SO now a good place to ask questions I must have an answer to in a "major hurry"? Because I thought it was a repository for high quality questions and answers, not a help desk.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Not sure how you arrived there - I simply said that quite a few of the more problematic questions come from people in a bit of a panic, and that anything designed to help them needs to understand that :)

Comment: Understood, but my complaint is that we seem to be bending over backwards to help questioners in a hurry, at the risk of alienating the answerers who take the time to present a good, well written, and well researched answers.