# Is there an ask page URL parameter for default question content?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, hyperlinks

I know I can add some parameters to prepopulate tags and titles like this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=mytag
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=mytitle
```

Is it possible to pre-populate the *content* field with some advice?  For example, I find that often users of the link I provide don't add important information like specific error messages or example log output.  I would like to give them that hint in the question page.

Comment: Some people just don't listen to advice. You can't save them. Doing all the work for them won't make things better.

Comment: Related: [Pre-fill question-box with text for new users (A/B study proposal)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278444) and [Let's send new users off to see the Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358600)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope*.

This would cause too many problems; without special validation, it'd be entirely possible to send folks to a form that they could submit directly, and generate a lot of noise as a result.

*...there is one exception: [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) offers three *templates* for posting apps, libraries, and scripts. These will pre-fill based on the `tags` parameter:

- Apps: https://stackapps.com/questions/ask?tags=app
- Libraries: https://stackapps.com/questions/ask?tags=library
- Scripts: https://stackapps.com/questions/ask?tags=script

In theory, this functionality is available everywhere... But those three are the only templates defined for questions on any site, so you're out of luck on Stack Overflow.

Comment: To prevent direct submission, just add this to the templates: "_Remember to avoid link shorteners like https://goo.gl or https://bit.ly, in your post. And don't forget to delete this paragraph._"

Comment: @Shog9 It is also possible to prefill the body in the area51 discussion zone (Proof: when you click on `create new discussion` the text box is prefilled with some standard text)

Answer (score 0):

Using the StackExchange API, you **can** pre-populate a question or even an answer. Check out the docs [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-question#tags=Julia&preview=true&filter=default&site=stackoverflow) and poke around. Basically, all user functionality in SO can be replicated using their API.

You would need actual code running for this to work, but if you can handle that, you are able to take user input and post it via the Stack Exchange API.

NOTE that this will not allow you to pre-fill a post using a link as you asked, but it could be. viable workaround depending on the use case.