# Why did I suddenly get "Review Your Question" button on Stack Overflow when asking a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, user-experience, ask-question-form

I've been using Stack Overflow for years and since the last two days (with the newest design changes on question posting) I've realized that I can't post a question directly. It says "Review Your Question" instead of the post button:

[image]

When I tap it, it reloads the page, and then I need to click the same button (in which case becomes the post question button) to actually post my question.

While not super-important, this flow is extremely annoying and a step backwards in user experience in my opinion. To be honest, I don't even review my question after hitting that button (I already review it before hitting post anyway). I just scroll down and hit the same button again.

Is that part of the new design, or something to do with my account? I couldn't find any sources regarding this issue on meta. Additionally, is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: It doesn't come up for me, so I'm not sure what exactly it does, but it *sounds* like it may be there to get users to look at how their question will look when posted before submitting. (Despite the fact that there's already a live preview, we already get so many questions that are unreadable due to unformatted code.) Since the preview appears to frequently be ignored, prodding users to think about how their question looks before posting it sounds like a great idea to me, we've needed something like it for a long time IMO. (though it's not helpful for experienced users...)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295683/

Comment: It is triggered by the quality of your past questions ... wait ...

Comment: Oh, now it's coming up for me, it looks like it's part of the [Ask](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369682/) wizard.

Comment: a "Review your answer" button could be handy, on the other hand...

Comment: I just asked a question and this didn't come up.

Comment: @JL2210 I think it's gradually rolled out, as some people are having it and some people not.

Comment: I should point out this is part of an [ask page A/B test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389438/thoughts-on-the-new-ask-public-question-page). (Which is why some people don't see it yet.) The idea is to make the review step, which you already do implicitly, explicit for people who don't do it. Obviously testing will determine if it's helping people ask better questions or just a roadblock.

Comment: I was lucky guy to have todays WTF moment after seeing this button. Really SO? Did I sign somewhere to be beta-tester? I am too old for that shift..

Comment: I got this button today and it hangs up chrome tab. Three times in the row :/

Comment: It is very successful at irritating me. I don't like it.