# Make closing the comment help intuitive for new users

Tags: feature-request, comments, new-users, user-interface

When I, a *new* user asked a question using this Ask Question wizard, I was shown the comment formatting help on every comment that I was posting under my question.

Can it be set to some threshold? 3-4 comments or when I had used some formatting tools should be enough to tell the UI to stop pestering me with the guide.

It can be closed using the "help" button, which is very unintuitive. As [suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389438/thoughts-on-the-new-ask-public-question-page/390799?noredirect=1#comment737521_390799) by Cody Gray, make it "toggle help" please?

> [image: comment screenshot]

Comment: There should already be some kind of threshold (it's probably a rep threshold), as I don't see this when I post a comment.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But its purpose is to show how to use the formatting. Rep doesn't guarantee that, usage does.

Comment: Not the ideal solution, but if you don't like it, you can use a trivial userscript to hide it via `display: none`