# What happened to the Ask Question Wizard / Guided Mode?

Tags: support, asking-questions, ask-question-wizard-2018, ask-question-form

I've only checked the Ask Question Wizard when it was in the prototype phase and shortly after it [went live](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381671/8967612). I was just trying to re-visit it now but I didn't have any luck.

In the post linked above, it says that:

> You can switch from traditional to guided mode at any time by clicking the **"Use guided mode"** link near the top. When in guided mode, you'll be able to switch to traditional mode after first answering a few questions - a "Use traditional mode" link will appear when this is available.
> [emphasis mine]

However, I can't really find that "Use guided mode" link anywhere and the `/ask/wizard` link just redirects me to `/ask`. What gives?!

Has the ability to use the wizard been removed from users above the reputation threshold? If so, why? Or has the wizard not been presented to all users for some time now?

Comment: AFAIK, the previous "Ask Question Wizard" with separate "guided mode" has been abandoned for the current ["new" Ask Question page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389438/2821954) for everyone instead. Also, refer to [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/241919) on MSE: "*The new page was designed with the goal of helping new askers by more readily presenting them with tips on how to improve their question. This is a combination of the "Ask a question wizard" (that was tested on Stack Overflow) and the current standard "ask a question" page.*"

Comment: @AndrewT. Hmm, that makes sense. Although I personally preferred the wizard as a tool to help new users. Anyway, the reason I wanted to revisit the wizard page was how [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404520/8967612) was written. It looked like the asker was following some kind of a template and I was wondering if that was something added to the wizard for when reporting bugs on meta. But I guess they probably just copied it from somewhere.

Comment: Looks like that's [the template from the dialog for the first-time poster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i2Bt.png).

Comment: Ah, you got that one right too :) Do you want to turn your original comment into an answer? I tried to find a Meta.SO post that documents the end of the Ask Question Wizard but I couldn't find one. Your comment summarized it very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Andrew said in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404521/what-happened-to-the-ask-question-wizard-guided-mode#comment819636_404521), the Ask Question Wizard was abandoned in favor of the new (current) ask page that [went live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/348196) on the network in March 2020. Here's a quote from that announcement post:

> The new page was designed with the goal of helping new askers by more readily presenting them with tips on how to improve their question. This is a combination of the "Ask a question wizard" (that was tested on Stack Overflow) and the current standard "ask a question" page.