# Make the "How to ask a good question" guide (much) more visible

Tags: feature-request, ask-question-form

I have been seeing so many homework/leetcode/whatever-website questions being asked on SO. They aren't good questions too. These people would just post the website question on SO, and call it a day expecting somebody to take time out of their day to answer their question. It sucks and I hate it, I'm guessing many of you guys do too. Actually, any question where the OP doesn't spend their time doing the necessary research before coming here gets annoying.

So I'm suggesting, from the bottom of my heart, putting the [*how to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) somewhere very, very visible. For example, if it's the first time a user posts a question, the page will pop up directly in their eyesight, which will hopefully make them read it (put some kind of time limit, so they don't scroll down and click next immediately). Or even a big button on the home screen would be nice.

Prime example: [Calculate birthday in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67479016/calculate-birthday-in-python)

Comment: SO has [ask question wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live) with your link among others. Not sure how would one make it more prominent...

Comment: @SurajRao:  Yes, we can *clearly* see [how effective the wizard is proving to be](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381794/1079354) if we're still needing to discuss people posting low-quality questions.

Comment: On the note of homework questions, I personally have a custom close reason for them when the OP fails to show the effort and research they *should* have. Don't forget, as well, there is a [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/2029983) on how to ask them too.

Comment: Those are easy to ignore, did it myself actually. I didnt even notice them.

Comment: @Makoto you can only lead a horse to the water...

Comment: @SurajRao: I think the point here is that there *is* no water.

Comment: We literally used to have how-to-ask as an *interstitial page*, forcing first-time askers to click through it before even seeing the ask page for the first time. Guess how that worked out.

Comment: @SurajRao SO _had_ the ask question wizard. Now it just has some boxes on the side with tips with only one expanded by default. See [What happened to the Ask Question Wizard / Guided Mode?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404521/7296893)

Comment: @BoltClock I have two guesses alright. There was chaos or No one read the page.

Comment: @BoltClock I can guess that it didn't go down well, but I'd rather it was that obvious instead of that damn cookie popup.

Comment: *"which will hopefully make them read it"* . Human nature suggests they won't. How many people actually read a site's terms of service as opposed to scroll immediately to the bottom and click on "Agree"

Comment: When was the last time you actually read through a license agreement which was popped up in your face?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While I don't disagree with this in principle, walls of text are easy to ignore and the pain of needing immediate help is real enough to simply not bother with any of our rules or guidelines.

So, the only effective tool we have to use when someone posts a poor question<sup>1</sup> is to just **downvote it**.  If it's off-topic, flag/vote for closure too.

<sup>1: Homework questions are actually allowed here, but if they're just assignment dumps, then they're easy enough to both downvote *and* close.</sup>

Comment: Ok sure I can downvote them and flag them, but the OP gets nothing out of this, just sad their question wasnt accepted. I though if we help the user make a good question they can get their question answered and feel happy about themselves.

Comment: Phrased another way @BuddyBobIII - the OP only got out what they put in.  If someone doesn't put effort in to being helped, I see no reason to lament the fact that I couldn't do anything about it.

Comment: If the help they want is help that SO isn't meant to provide, nothing we do will make them happy short of helping them anyway and making this place worse over time.

Comment: Questions don't get "accepted" here @BuddyBobIII ; they are either aren't well received (and often as a result closed), well received (and often as a result draw high quality answers), or disappear in the void due to not being good enough to attract much attention (perhaps a single answer with few votes as well) while not being bad enough to attract much attention either. Many, recently, fall into the latter; they aren't *bad* questions but nor are they really *good*. Likely a little bit of research or time from the OP would have yielded a really good question (or made it moot).

Answer (score -4):

I don't expect everyone to be able to write museum-quality questions. I try hard to look for ways that I can edit and answer before I look for reasons that something should be closed or flagged. I'm saying that because it's important to me that people know we're not out looking for any reason under the sun to not like something, we just get *a lot* of unanswerable questions, and it wears on folks.

With that said, all of the text in the world isn't going to help someone that doesn't see their question as a contribution, or doesn't grasp the level of research they really need to know how to do. They're not *trying* to annoy anyone, they just want some help, and they see their question as the hardest thing they need to do that day. It's huge to them and they don't yet know how to break the problem down.

When people develop a history of doing this over time, especially in short succession, their ability to ask is diminished. There are people that just don't care about their effect on others and we actively discourage them with automatic limits and even automatic question blocks - and moderators tend to look out for these folks continuing to find ways to drag mud on the floors.

But *most* folks do improve over time. They may not ever ask those thought-provoking REALLY interesting questions, but they get the hang of it. The best thing you can do is just use your votes.

I like to remind folks that the *vast* majority of questions are pretty well-received:

[image: graph showing upvotes vs downvotes]

It's important to keep in mind when you see a train of 100 hastily-written questions missing lots of needed info roll by. Old questions still get votes too, so that's not representative of *just* new questions, but you can see how things settle.

The best thing you can do is as Makoto suggests - downvote if you want, cast a close vote if you can and think you should, ***edit*** if you think you can help something get over the edge where it's answerable and remember it's a marathon we're all running. This is supposed to be rewarding.

I think we could be doing more for people to help them (early on) understand this. I think there's a value proposition in it that we could capture in the editor for folks new to getting programming help (the Wizard was a good first attempt). I think "it" is out there, though it continues to elude us.

Walls of text and forced delays just infuriate people when they're in a hurry; I don't think that's the "it" we're trying to find.

Comment: `Walls of text and forced delays just infuriate people when they're in a hurry` -- **You still have to try.**  The only thing worse than being told what to do, and then being told what to do again when you ignore the advice the first time, is *not being told what to do at all.*

Comment: `the vast majority of questions are pretty well-received:` -- I think you're misreading that graph.  All it says is that people are more predisposed to upvoting rather than downvoting.  It says nothing about the "train of 100 hastily-written questions" that nobody can be arsed to even look at.

Comment: Nice and misleading data. Let's check the actual numbers for the last month: in the first 48 hours of asking, new questions got an average score of -0.6, clearly below 0, with a slight decreasing trend [source](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1395791/votes-within-48-hours-of-new-questions-last-month#graph).

Comment: Oh, and while we're on the subject of slightly misleading graphs, check out [this nice one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1395793/percentage-of-upvoted-vs-downvoted-questions-over-time#graph) showing the percentage of upvoted questions vs the total number of upvoted and downvoted questions (including deleted ones) over time. There are some biases there, but surely less than in the graph you shared

Comment: I wonder how much of an impact the trend of people using upvotes to counter perceived "toxicity" has on graphs like this

Comment: I'm only slightly dissatisfied with "downvote if you want", because this implies that when given the situation of seeing poor questions *and* we have a vested interest in not keeping those questions on the site, that we have a *choice* to either take action or not take action.  Encouraging more people to downvote would go a longer way towards dealing with the very, very real problem that - despite the *data* saying one thing, the reality is quite different.  There really are questions that just...suck, and should be downvoted.

Comment: People in a hurry should never ask questions on SO. There is no way that such questions can be a good ones. And it is disservice to those that do want to participate in positive manner when they are not told what is expected of them to begin with. This is single point of failure of SO. Having hard rules and hiding them.

Comment: If this is a real graph of upvotes vs downvotes on new questions then something is really wrong. There isn't so many good questions asked anymore to attract so many upvotes. Maybe you are considering votes cast on old questions and answers?