# Guidance on the posting form is actively counterproductive vs how-to-ask guidelines

Tags: feature-request, ask-question-form

Whenever one goes to "Ask a Question" on Stack Overflow, the fields are labelled like so:

**Title**

*Be specific and imagine you’re asking a question to another person*

**Body**

*Include all the information someone would need to answer your question*

The natural interpretation for many new users, who have not read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and have not had it thrown in their faces, is:

*Be specific* -> "hmm, I should make sure I write a fair bit in here"

*imagine you're asking a question to another person* -> "I should use conversational language, give brief context and describe the situation in terms that are specific to my own code"

*Include all the information someone would need to answer your question* -> "Well, they'll have to see the code, I guess"

In the worst case, that gives you the initial revision of questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72455156). It's hard to argue that OP didn't do exactly what was asked, outside of not actually ending the title with a sentence that naturally ends with a `?` (and actually using one). There isn't anything said about *omitting* irrelevant parts of the code, and OP doesn't have a good enough conception of the problem to think of anything outside the code that could be needed.

The form labels are **actively hurting** (i.e., inspiring new users to ask worse questions than they would otherwise), because they encourage the OP to try to cram the context of the problem into the title (rather than putting it in the post where it belongs) and avoid summarizing the question (contra the how-to-ask advice of "write the title last").

If we [can't have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404521) an ask-question wizard, or if it's [still in development... again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ask-question-wizard-2022), can we at least have

a) a *prominent* link to how-to-ask

b) better guidance text

on the question form? In fact, I think we should have those things anyway.

---

Edit: here is a quick proposal for the guidance text.

**Title**

*Summarize your question in a single sentence. Consider coming back to this after writing the question.*

**Body**

*Be detailed and specific, but focus on what is relevant to your question. Make clear what goes wrong, how it goes wrong, and exactly what you need to know. If you are asking about already existing code, include it; try to create a [mre] if you can. See [ask] for more help.*

Comment: "Consider coming back to this after writing the question" - I'd go even further than that: "Write it **after** you've composed the question". We end up with so many crap titles because, apparently, no one in high school/university told these people summaries are written after the work is complete.

Comment: "*Summarize your question in a single sentence.*" => "Summarize your question in a single sentence [containing (all/most) keywords you would use to search for an answer]." :idea:

Comment: Hum..., I realize 1 day later, that my Sugg about adding "*containing the keywords you would use to search for an answer*" is maybe not "such a good idea", as it may "conflict" with the Tag System and the general(?) Rule/Guideline not to mention Tags in a Title... (I was just trying to address the "Problem" that I very often find Question Titles "not very descriptive" about their Content...)