# How about an interactive welcoming tutorial?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, welcoming

Some students [say](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/09/30/the-loop-september-2020-summer-bridge-to-tech-for-kids/?fbclid=IwAR0opBTuxS-hgP7-6Zh11b4-DXldUcQtzYStp2oglzeUoWsbNKr4ZkTuBmA):

> without a clear understanding of the community’s rules, it was hard to get started. [...] it seemed like the site punished people for not knowing how to engage with the community in the right way

How about making an interactive tutorial when someone is trying to register?

> **Do you know what is expected from you?**
>
> - Yes
>
>   - Make an Audit, probably 3 multiple choice questions?
> - Explain it to me
>
>   - Something interactive like the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), but with focus on Community
>     Standards
> - I don't care
>
>   - **STOP!** Look, Listen
>   - Continue with "Explain it to me"

I think what we want to teach them is open to discussion, but I also think that this way no one can say *I didn't know* anymore.

It's great to give new people the opportunity to ask great questions and feel more welcoming. Let's teach them. But please do not change the Mission of the site by accepting low quality.

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to do what you propose without seeming condescending, and I don't think taking away folks' "I didn't know" excuse should be the primary goal.

Comment: Okay, that was a bit misleading expressed. The main goal I mean is *It's great to give new people the opportunity to ask great questions and feel more welcoming. Let's teach them.* @RobertHarvey

Comment: I think a general [question wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard) is better here... since this an issue with people asking questions.

Comment: I would suggest making a video. That seems to be the only thing young people understand these days.

Comment: They don't want to be taught, or learn from pages of rules/policy/guidelines.  They want their question answered now, and everything else is irrelevant noise thst will inevitably be Facepalmed and Tottered as unwelcoming and toxic.  Nothing can be done.  New users cannot be identified, new accounts cannot be filtered to avoid the trolls and selfish deadbeats.  It's over.

Comment: @TylerH Why not both? A question wizard and an introductory wizard/tour. Just having a page for visiting the tour page doesn't work, but something that doesn't go away that easily in the beginning and maybe before asking the very first question might make an impact. I see it a big like traffic signs. There are so many of them that even lazy people can't help noticing some of them.

Comment: I need to look into what the *current* SO onboarding consists of, but I'm under the impression that it could use some definite improvements, and that improvements to it would benefit *everyone*, the Company and the Community both. Throwing in the towel to say "well, it's all hopeless anyway" sounds really... dumb, to me. I'm not as jaded towards SO as many here, but "it's all hopeless" is certainly not going to make anything better overall, for either party, *or* new users.

Comment: @zcoop98 I, myself, suggested that intro pages should be timed to try and persuade new users to read them and to inconvenience account-per-question vamps.  It was soundly rejected as a 'barrier to new users'.  SO would rather waste the time of curators than, even mildly, inconvenience selfish deadbeats who read ads.  It's all about bums on sites.

Comment: This is the perfect use-case for forced advertisement video technology. Like have a boolean flag on users like `watched_intro` (for new users it's set to false) and if it's false, then they are forced to watch an ad (which is a stackoverflow intro video), and use the technology that advertisers use where you cannot skip it, adblockers don't work (more specifically, `watched_intro` isn't set to true if adblockers are blocking the video), and the user must watch the video to the end before `watched_into` is set to true.

Comment: It could start by using the energy put into April fool (e.g. a game) and evolve from there.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt What was the punishment they felt they experienced? If we knew that, we might be able to do something about why the question was such that "punishment" was administered.

Comment: I like to think of this topic with a lawnmower example. Stack Overflow is a mower. Everyone's used a mower (it's just another forum site amirite?) Stack has a detailed manual of his *this* mower works. Users buy it from the store, set it up, put gas in and go. They don't care about how to maintain it, or what oil and gas to use. they just want their dang grass cut. A user is silly and didn't read the user manual and cut their hand off or their grass got killed. They complain. It's a real issue for the manufacturer! They believe they have to solve it. People who read the manual get tired of it.

Comment: "...but I also think that this way no one can say I didn't know anymore." -- "A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools." Douglas Adsms

Comment: The trouble is that the lack of understanding of the site tends to be a side effect, not the root problem. The root problem is a personal mindset, people coming to Stack Overflow thinking "I deserve ALL the help! I am young/I am in trouble/I am kind. Nice people, help me swiftly!". Such a mindset is welcomed with open arms on a large variety of websites... but on Stack Overflow it does not work. How do you flip the mindset of people such that the documentation as it exists is sought out and understood? A hard problem, for sure. An automated nag feature is not going to do it.

Comment: When you click "Ask a public question" - why isn't take the tour top of the right hand box before the guidance? Typical student flow: programming problem > Google > StackOverflow answers in results > click  "Ask a public question". Are there links to exemplar questions where the things we are looking for are "walked" through?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Or winter bash

Comment: @Gimby: Yes, all measures for educating newbies ~"in an automated way" will be circumvented (even the `watched_video` tag - just go to YouTube until the SO video finished playing). I'm sure this has been suggested before, but I maybe new questions (and maybe even answers!) by newbies should not publicly appear on the site **at all** - they could be put into a queue, and they might even be deleted automatically after a few days, **unless** they are approved by, let's say, 3 silver tag badge owners. That could help. (Corollary: It won't happen either... :-( )

Comment: @Marco13 There are not enough silver-taggers for that. But we could use the review queues that are *already* in place. All new posts are put there already. All we need to do is to make the posts pending until they clear the queues.

Comment: @Marco13 There is a SO video for newbies?

Comment: @Marco13 it has been suggested before. And just like all the previous times the response is the same; Stack Overflow is just too darned busy, bub :) Good luck screening thousands of questions, it'll probably just move the problem of the never-ending close vote queue to the screening queue. That's what makes Stack Overflow so fascinating; it's a whole different ballgame to reason about solving problems it has because of the sheer volume of traffic and data.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

How about *never gonna happen*?

The fundamental problems are that Stack Exchange Inc. (a) doesn't appear to want to invest anything into actually improving Stack Overflow (b) is actively opposed to anything that will raise the bar to entry and therefore discourage new user activity. Your suggestion (and every suggestion proposed by the community so far) will have that side-effect, therefore it will never be implemented. Fin.

That blog post is, like most of SE Inc.'s blog posts since Jeff left, fundamentally dishonest corporate feel-good waffle. It's easy to get a few interns to throw together some presentations saying the same things that the Meta community has been saying for years - considering the impact our suggestions have had over the course of more than a decade, it's laughable to expect that SE Inc. will all of a sudden start listening.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts! Anything like that would be viewed by SE Inc. as "unwelcoming".

Comment: I think user registrations are tied to success, possibly as the primary goal of SE. It might take even a different business plan to get out of this situation. Also I've been wondering for a while, your avatar is a [Homeworld reference](https://homeworld.fandom.com/wiki/Kiith#Kiith_S.27jet), right?

Comment: @jrh Indeed, the original *Homeworld* is my favourite game of all time. With the sigil of Kiith S'jet as my avatar, I honour the great people of the original Relic Entertainment who  crafted an experience that no other game I've played (and I've played many) has ever come close to emulating.

Comment: @IanKemp we might be getting off track here but I can't really think of a better way to do this, yeah, it's a great game, you can still play HW and Cata through GameRanger; I attempted to track down all the multiplayer maps from the old days but I was quite unsuccessful unfortunately (do you remember Hillx7's Hyper Football and Great Barrier Reefa? Seems like they have gone to data heaven.) It's a pity that the light corvette rush meta is so overpowered, most builds end up being a race to who can make them first / the mastest.

Comment: Why are we viewing this as an all or nothing, whole site roll out? SO has done A/B testing in the past, usually for things that matter substantially less. Why can't it be performed here in part and results analyzed after to see what effect it has on user retention?

Comment: @code11 Did you read my answer? Namely the part where Stack Exchange Inc. isn't going to do this because they don't want to?

Comment: Can't argue with A) for sure. For B), the proposed A/B testing would determine the extent  of impact on new user activity. Are you saying they wouldn't even run the experiment?

Comment: @code11 Correct.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to hear, but probably the answer I expected. I follow your argumentation.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt It may never happen, but still it's a good idea. That's why it was good to ask for it.

Comment: @IanKemp , whats the reason they dont want to imporve SO

Answer (score 36):

I don't think this'd work, specifically because we're talking to students - a demographic which has [given us a lot of angst in the past](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

It'd be a lot better to figure out what it is students are actually looking for when engaging on a site like Stack Overflow, first.  Because, students vary.

Do these students expect Stack Overflow to:

- Fill the role of a tutor and show them how to code?
- Be able to help explain their homework or problems to them in a simpler way?
- Give pointers on their assignments on how to "make it better"?
- Expect that they are beginners and not try to give advice which is over their heads?
- Engage with them in a more one-on-one setting (a-la tutoring), but in the context of a specific problem?

Because I'm going to tell you straight up:  until we figure out what these students are actually trying to get out of the site, putting together some prose about what we want them to do on the site [is just likely going to get ignored](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398459/1079354).

Comment: I used to be a student, so I know why people come to SO for help: Because SO seems like a site where you can ask almost any question, and get answers out of. Most students don't have good professors so out of desperation they come here. And tbh, can we blame them?

Comment: I'm not their professor @10Rep, nor can I be a suitable surrogate for a professor, and I *tutor* students in CompSci on the side.  That might be the start of the disconnect, in that we're being used to supplement their education in a way that doesn't seem *exactly* equitable to all parties.  Could we start there and talk about it before they just throw their assignments at us?

Comment: Perhaps. But whatever the solution be, it needs to be _unskippable_. The reason why we get so much junk is because people don't read [ask], and [tour]. Some don't even read the Code of Conduct, even. So this tutorial needs to be unskippable.

Comment: Oh it'll be skippable. If nothing else, students are clever about ways on how to get out of doing things.

Comment: Sure, but it shouldn't be _directly skippable_. As in, no x button until you scroll to the bottom. It's easy to skip, but we should try what's in our hands. And most people want an answer, so we just put at the top that says "Read this, or you won't get an answer!" or something.

Comment: I don't see you selling a feature that discourages user engagement to a platform that is actively soliciting more user engagement.  But who knows; maybe this is an opportunity to be optimistic.  I just don't see Stack Exchange going forward with something that limits the number of account sign ups.

Comment: I gotta say I disagree with this answer. Instead of teaching them what *we* expect, you're focusing instead on what *they* (students or otherwise) expect. That seems nearly irrelevant from my standpoint; we need better enforcement of *our* policies, completely irregardless of what a new user may be coming here for. The teaching and instruction of new users is key here, pushing the rules of our community over their expectations or preconceived notions.

Comment: @zcoop98 knowing what they expect is a big step toward being able to enforce our policies in a way that we'd hopefully not end up back at this discussion every semester.

Comment: Ruling with an iron fist clearly hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: @zcoop98:  You're not gonna get better enforcement of our policies, since - and I'm not really sure if you've been around in the last couple of years or so - there has been a steady erosion of the clout that we have when it comes to talking about what we expect.  The benevolent dictators are becoming less benevolent, and at the end of the day it's easier to go *around* their perception of what the community is and just ask students directly.  At the end of the day, we are only given the power that Stack Exchange chooses to lend us.  I'd rather set expectations than wield authority.

Comment: @Makoto All fair and true. I haven't been around that long, but I've read enough about that recent(ish) erosion and the events that have come out of it to know what you mean.

Comment: @10Rep something you may be unaware of (and excuse me if I am telling you something you already know). University lecturers are not hired to teach. They are hired to do research and teaching is just an extra duty they need to perform. Just because someone is very good in his area of expertise does not make him a good teacher. So I understand where a student is coming from but they still need to try and find the answer themselves before posting a question on SO. I get the impression that many of them do zero research before posting a question.

Comment: The reason why there is so much crap is because the company wants quantity over quality. What you are saying in this post is just the same old debate, here's a [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251795/584518) from me in 2014 about the homework problem. That was in the very start of the "Spolsky era". Homework is now a much worse problem than it was back then. ->

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think the problem can be solved no matter how many good suggestions we come up with, until we get rid of the company. Because it is quite clear that they are never going to implement anything that reduces homework begging site traffic. Once upon a time they cared about helping professional & enthusiast programmers, but that was almost a decade ago.

Comment: This answer suggests we should have an introductory "what do you hope to get here" questionnaire during registration? Or what would be the best way to get to know the intentions of newly registered students? Judging by the questions I see I would say that while sometimes people ask for complete solutions to their homework problems, this is still a minority and the majority is "just" badly formulated, unsearched programming problems, mostly debugging problems. If only we had a better way to teach newly registered users how to debug...

Comment: I might be projecting here, but students may not be contributing because they may not understand that "sharing is caring".  For the first 18-22 years of their lives, they have been on the receiving end of knowledge, force-fed from doctrine; they may not understand the big picture is a give and take dynamic. That yesterdays students are today's teachers. I certainly did not in my younger years. If you don't understand both sides of the coin, you may not understand the social contract.

Comment: The list "Do these students expect Stack Overflow to ..." is missing "... supply the code needed for their assignment". It's a very common first users' 'question'.

Comment: @KevinB We haven't ruled with an iron fist, because SE Inc. has thwarted any attempts to. Please don't paint us as the bad guys when we're physically unable to be.

Comment: @Abra That's actually something new to me. Some students who ask low quality questions have professors who don't teach _at all_. I understand that the professors aren't paid to teach, but to do research, but nevertheless when a student is faced with the prospect of doing a 100 point assignment that they don't know how to do, they come here. And tbh we can't blame them.

Comment: @10Rep: we *can* blame them for not "researching" what kind of questions are appropriate here (it's in the Tour, the Help, and it also should be fairly visible from a cursory browsing through questions and answers).

Comment: @usr2564301 It's a maze. It's so much a maze that some of the things in the Help Center needs extra clarifications on meta and that's a two months dive into the maze. It's not userfriendly in any way. **And** that's when users actually try! Most people, including professions don't read the manual, and everyone knows it.

Comment: @usr2564301 Exactly what Scratte said. When I first came here, I read the manual, a lot. I took the tour, read the help center, and even read the about us, read the CoC, and I read the licenses. But my first question is now deleted, after a comment telling me to RTFM. And about professors, tbh, the board should hire people who can teach, not people who read off a power point and stress students out, which is what I'm facing right now. And by the way, my first question _did_ include code. I honestly gave an attempt. I didn't just dump my assignment in a question.

Comment: @10Rep:  I too started here as a student and yet we have had very different experiences.  I do feel like I did comb through documentation and I didn't really engage until I knew I could ask a comprehensive and coherent question.  Yes, that did raise the barrier to entry, but that barrier to entry did make me really go all out for my first question.

Comment: @Makoto Perhaps I'm not the "Read a manual" type :). And that raises a point: why is it a manual?  Why can't it be a video along with it? Not everyone is a textual learner. I learn better when I listen/see something. I'd rather have a video of some sort, instead of a huge mass of text that takes experience to understand. And most sites engage users with an interactive tour, by hovering over all the buttons. Why can't we have that? That wouldn't decrease user signups, would it? But SE will only implement things that give them profit :(.

Comment: @10Rep:  There's a balance between Kumbaya and RTFM that the company actually can't determine, since it's the community would have to be the ones willing to actively engage and produce that material.  You know, the people who *actually* use the site on a daily basis.  However, we're only here on a volunteer basis and we feel/trust that our plea of "write a clear question that doesn't sound like it's asking for a lot of work from us volunteers" is reasonable enough. The problem is that it's often masked as an attack or an offense to others who "just want to learn".

Comment: @Makoto It's true that it's in our hands how such questions are recieved/written. But when I came here, I immediately understood that this community is different from other helpdesks... NOT. I didn't see anything that told me, "Asking a low quality question is not a good thing, see, look at other users being punished for it!". I was never told that putting "Hope this Helps!" in an answer is considered fluff, and that people will downvote bc of it! Even the CEO of StackOverflow puts "Hope this helps!" in one of their posts on another site. I think learning by experience/examples is more

Comment: beneficial than learning from a huge mass of text. But maybe it's just me who thinks this.

Comment: @10Rep The thing you have to remember is that (nearly) all programming is *text* (unless you're using LabView or something). All day long, I look at and manipulate text. The manuals I read are written in text. This isn't to discriminate against visual learners or anything, and I'm all for videos and whatnot that teach (mainly) the younger generation how to program, but until HollywoodOS is a reality and we can program by using 3D workstations and glowing pictograms, text is what programming is all about. (Yes, I'm purposely ignoring UI design.)

Comment: I signed up on Stack Overflow as a person who is (incidentally) a student. I read the site rules, I knew what Stack Exchange sites were for, I came here to _answer_, not ask questions (though I’m mostly curating content nowadays). None of the five suggested bullet points fit my expectations. I know, this answer isn’t a finished proposal, but keep in mind that, if you’re going to find out which accounts belong to students — e.g. by asking them “Are you a student? [Yes] [No]” —, that _a few_ users are actually willing to positively contribute to the community, _Make The Internet A Better Place_.

Answer (score 25):

New user onboarding on Stack Overflow is a service problem.  (Most) new users don't care about this sites mission at all, they probably don't even know it.  They see a lot of answers to questions and figure that they can get answers to their questions too.  You can tell them that this site aims to build a repository of useful information until you are blue in the face, but they came here to get an answer to their question, no matter how bad or poorly conceived.

The service problem is that there are people that are willing to answer questions, no matter how bad they are.  This is "good" for the new user, but bad for the site.  Unless something keeps bad new users from receiving answers until they are aligned with the site's mission, there is no recourse and no amount of tutorials or wizards will help.

To you and I, a tutorial would help a user understand how this crazy symbiotic Stack Overflow relationship works where a user asks a good, thought out, researched question with no expectation on when an answer will be received in order to help the *next* poor dev that runs into the *same* issue get to the solution more quickly.

However, to a bad new user, a tutorial is more akin to the bad parts of a timeshare presentation.  They don't want or care about the actual timeshare and are only here for the free Disney World tickets.

Comment: What is a *"timeshare presentation"*? A US phenomenon? Was it described in [Robert J. Ringer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Ringer)'s *"Million Dollar Habits"*?

Comment: *"[Because of their notorious reputation, timeshare companies tempt you with freebies like dinner vouchers, concert tickets, or awesome vacations.](https://twocents.lifehacker.com/how-to-attend-a-timeshare-presentation-just-for-the-fre-1739071798)"*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes, I think it is mostly a US thing.  They end up being scams that are billed as a shared ownership of a vacation property but the fees and conditions end up making them less than ideal and the contracts are often inescapable.  However, advertisers will lure in prospective buyers with crazy incentives (free hotel nights, amusement park tickets, a boat) with the caveat that you just have to listen to a presentation on the timeshare.  Many go in saying "I'll just get the free stuff", but some still get trapped.

Comment: Heh, the most accurate answer I've ever read. Bravo.

Answer (score 13):

There are several layers that could be unpacked here, and it's hard to address *each* of them in all detail.

At the first glance, this sounds like a good idea to solve some of the homebrewn problems: New users coming to the site with wrong expectations *is* a problem. Roughly speaking: Someone has 99 programming problems, and 98 of them can be solved with Google, Stack Overflow, Copy+Paste and Trial+Error. The last one is taken down and passed around, as a new ""question"", saying: "Hey, solve *this* one for me as well".

But I think that you underestimate the efforts that people are willing to invest in order to ... reduce the effort that they have to invest. What you are suggesting sounds a bit like a CAPTCHVA: A "Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Contributors and HelpVampires Apart". But people will just jump through these hoops. They will click some multiple-choice-checkboxes and fill out text fields. In doubt, there will be sites that tell them which checkboxes they have to click and which text they have to enter in order to pass the test!

And then they will ask their low-quality questions.

It might be a hurdle that could prevent some people from asking homework questions "too easily" - meaning that there might be a bit *fewer* of these questions. But without strict curation, it will still not be possible to cope with the incoming stream of low-quality content.

Of course, "curation" here means what can then be portayed as hostility, non-welcomingness, punishment, toxicity, or honesty. This leads to another layer, which is, once more, the political one: If this approach is likely to *reduce* the number of active users or site interactions, or prevents *some* people (in obscure and arbitrary ways) from participating, then it's not gonna happen - even when you give it a nice, shiny, wholesome name like "The Welcoming™ Tutorial". Or to put it that way: When the goals that *could* (optimistically) be achieved with this approach are not in line with the goals of the company, then there's no reason to put effort into this.

<sup>And an aside: I think that such a tutorial should simply not be *necessary*. I mean, Stack Overflow has accumulated thousands of [mavens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maven) for many years, and achieved its original goals with not much more than saying: "Be nice", and establishing an unprecedented system for the moderation and curation of high-quality question and answers. Of course, not everything was perfect, and there have been some problems (none of which have been related to politics and demographics, by the way), but it worked *astonishingly* well.</sup>

Comment: This. Good users are going to ask good (or at least salvageable) questions without the extra help, and crappy users are going to ask crappy questions regardless.

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned, there are two categories of new users.  Those that care about the site and genuinely want to use it correctly, and those that only care about getting their own problem solved and then disappear.  Nothing we do with regards to onboarding will help with the latter group, because you can't really convert users from the latter group to the former (I'd be delighted to be proven wrong).

That being said, we shouldn't let our cynicism prevent us from helping the first group as much as we can. Minimizing the number of users that get converted from the first group to the second is a worthy goal even if it doesn't solve 100% of the quality problems.  I think a more interactive onboarding experience would be a good idea indeed (at least I would have found it useful back when I first joined the site).  The one issue I see with it is that you can get stuck in a cycle of "I don't understand" -> "Explain it to me" -> "I still don't understand" -> "Explain it to me" -> etc.  Currently if the official documentation isn't sufficient for you, then you don't really have any way to get more information.  It would be nice if there was a "talk to a human" option that would drop you into a "new user help" chat where some of the mods, staff, and/or power users lurked.  That would give honest new users a chance to ask any questions they have about the site and get clarification before they jump in and make a mistake.  If chat isn't practical, you could also provide a form for asking a question, which would then get posted to meta with a special "site question from new user" tag.  As questions come in, we'll get an idea of what parts of the tour/documentation are lacking and need improvement.

Comment: You raise an interesting point here. In a perfect world, that would be a real thing to consider. It was hard to choose the accepted answer, but I left with Ian's :(