# Giving search help on homework questions

Tags: discussion, answers

I came across [this homework question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198280/how-to-use-data-from-text-file-using-jfilechooser/27198372#27198372) earlier. The asker asked a specific question, so I helped lead them in the right direction, but they also stated they wanted more info about what they were working with. My question is, would it be better to directly link to the documentation for it or guide them to search for the documentation and other relevant information?

**EDIT:** I was going to say something like "You can search for the documentation and other useful information by searching 'jfilechooser documentation'". My reasoning was:

1. In case the link broke in the future, since there really was no good way to add the information to the answer
2. The asker will get the official documentation likely as the first result, but also other non-official but still useful resources

Alternative: Would it be best to do both?

**EDIT #2:**
I would like to clarify that the question *was* on topic. The asker asked for debugging help, posted the desired behavior, and the relevant code ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the help center). My question is about how to answer it.

Comment: Without a link to that specific question, it's hard to give you specific advice. Generally, dont' link to documentation; rather if they have an answerable problem, answer it and quote the documentation as needed. If their question meets the criteria for closing, vote to close it or flag for closure.

Comment: I'll add the link to the question. The answer didn't require the documentation, but I wanted to direct them to more information if they needed it.

Comment: Remember that your answer is not just for the benefit of the asker, but anyone who happens across it later. I feel we should generally just link to documentation, rather than search queries. Anyone paying attention will learn that the documentation site is a good resource they can take advantage of in the future.

Comment: Long experience here tells me that many, maybe most students aren't even aware of the existence of official documentation, and instead piece together knowledge from course materials and tutorials. So I always make a point to link official docs to anything related. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252439/how-to-answer-a-homework-question-when-the-entire-example-is-bad-syntax/252441#252441

Comment: @gnat No, the question is on-topic. My question is about how to answer it.

Comment: SO's culture is different from other forums. We don't want to encourage "use the searchbar" mentalities, but rather to provide detailed and correct answers.

Comment: I think you did basically the right thing here.  Hints and pointers are an excellent way to answer homework questions.

Comment: Not sure why this was marked as a duplicate, the questions are **not** the same. The question marked as duplicate is about answering off-topic questions, this is not.

Answer (score 31):

Please NEVER post an answer along the lines of "you could google XYZ".  Because if you do, then the next person looking for an answer to XYZ googles it, and finds your very helpful advice telling them to google it.

In the early days of Stack Overflow, this happened a lot.  I was not a big user of Stack Overflow in the early days.  I just used google directly to look for answers to my problems.  I just knew Stack Overflow as the site that always came up in my search results, telling me to use google.

Comment: Yes, this happens to me very regularly.

Comment: That is pretty hilarious, I had almost forgotten about this.

Comment: Thank you. I promise I'll never advise to _"ask your friend Google first"_ again. There were cases where I did write to ask Google, but thinking twice now, all such questions **has been closed** (too broad or off topic). Questions like _"How to learn Java"_, _"How to create an user control that does a) b) c) d) e) f) ..."_ Best move is to link to the general documentation, the help center, in comments, then close vote the question. I think this Google endless loop should be addressed in the 
**[Help Center > Answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**

Answer (score 16):

Thanks everyone for commenting. Here's what stood out from the comments:

1. Not every beginner knows that official documentation exists
2. Linking directly to the documentation shows them that it exists and is a good resource
3. However, links sometimes gets broken
4. It is better to give people the information than to tell them to search for it

So in the end, answering the question, then linking directly to the documentation (while quoting the relevant part of that documentation whenever possible) appears to be the best option.

Comment: "linking directly to the documentation appears to be the best option." no, you should include what part of the documentation is relevant to the problem asked, and offer the link for more information.

Comment: @mason [check the revision history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/278078/revisions), it saves you many misunderstandings.

Answer (score -2):

Being a beginner myself I say that the best way to help someone is to briefly explain the exact problem in their code and how it should be done. As a student I have a 800 page book + hundreds of slides describing what to do. I can promise that I've been through that a few times before I ask the question. More reading material is not what I need. And once I have a answer, if you give a good description to why it fails I will remember it.

Comment: `I can promise that I've been through that a few times before I ask the question.` Well, you are probably one of the rare diligent students - most of the home-work like questions I see on SO are crap.

Comment: Well after my first account got blocked for asking to stupid questions I've learned

Comment: @stian - Don't bother the downvote. They mean _"I won't (always) follow what you suggest"_ than _"you're wrong"_ (no effect on your rep.) On meta, we use the up/down vote to agree/disagree. Giving a straightforward answer is rarely sufficient for beginners. Most of them constantly ask ***new*** endless questions in comments, piling a stack of new issues that has nothing to do there... crap questions actually, because they failed to be honest and organized, slicing their issues in smaller and more specific parts and guess what : most of those specific issues are already answered here...

Comment: thank you, I was getting somewhat worried. After all my answer was not that bad